# FFMPEG and JNI - pass AVFrame data to Java and Back

Tags: java, c, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I have some C code that decodes a video frame by frame. I get to a point where i have an AVFrame in BGR32 and would like to send it back to Java for editing.

I have a ByteBuffer object in my C code that was created in Java using *AllocateDirect* but i struggle to write the content of the AVFrame->data[0] (of uint8_t type) to it and read it back. I have tried memcpy with no luck. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

UPDATE
Followed Will's comment below and wrote this in C

```
char *buf = (*pEnv)->GetDirectBufferAddress(pEnv, byteBuffer);
memcpy(buf, rgb_frame->data[0], output_width*output_height*4);
```

The buffer does contain some data in Java but doing the following returns a null bitmap

```
BufferedImage frame = ImageIO.read(bitmapStream);
```

Where bitmapStream is a ByteBufferInputStream defined here:
https://code.google.com/p/kryo/source/browse/trunk/src/com/esotericsoftware/kryo/io/ByteBufferInputStream.java?r=205

Not sure if I am not writing things correctly in this buffer

UPDATE 2

Got pretty close now thanks to the latest snippet. I am using BGR32 format in my C code ie 4 bytes per pixel. So I modified things a bit in Java:

```
final byte[] dataArray = new byte[width*height*4];
imageData.get(dataArray);
final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);
final DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(dataArray, dataArray.length);
Raster raster = Raster.createRaster(sampleModel, buffer, null);
image.setData(raster);
```

I get the image correctly but there seems to be an issue with color channels
[image: Example]

Tried different formats with no luck

Comment: edited answer to respond to your update

Comment: edited answer to respond to your update again

Comment: I would recommend to try TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR

Comment: I couldnt get 4BYTE_BGR to work at all to get a picture. The correct code that worked eventually is the one suggested below.

Comment: another option is to use image.copyData() with example in the re-edited answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle's JNI Functions Documentation at
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetDirectBufferAddress

> GetDirectBufferAddress

```
void* GetDirectBufferAddress(JNIEnv* env, jobject buf);
```

> Fetches and returns the starting address of the memory region
>   referenced by the given direct java.nio.Buffer.
>
> This function allows native code to access the same memory region that
>   is accessible to Java code via the buffer object. LINKAGE:
>
> Index 230 in the JNIEnv interface function table. PARAMETERS:
>
> env: the JNIEnv interface pointer
>
> buf: a direct java.nio.Buffer object (must not be NULL) RETURNS:
>
> Returns the starting address of the memory region referenced by the
>   buffer. Returns NULL if the memory region is undefined, if the given
>   object is not a direct java.nio.Buffer, or if JNI access to direct
>   buffers is not supported by this virtual machine. SINCE:
>
> JDK/JRE 1.4

I tested with this C++ code:

```
static char framebuf[100];

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_javaapplication45_UseByteBuffer_readBuf
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject usebb, jobject bb) {
    void *addr = env->GetDirectBufferAddress(bb);
    framebuf[0] = 77;
    memcpy(addr,framebuf,100);
}
```

and this Java Code:

```
public class UseByteBuffer {
    public native void readBuf(ByteBuffer bb);
}
```

...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.load("/home/shackle/NetBeansProjects/usebb/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/libusebb.so");
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(100);
    new UseByteBuffer().readBuf(bb);
    byte first_byte = bb.get(0);
    System.out.println("first_byte = " + first_byte);
}
```

And it printed the first_byte=77 indicating it got the data copied correctly.

**Update**

ImageIO.read() will not accept just any set of bytes it has to be in a format that one of the installed ImageReader's can recognize such as JPEG or PNG.

Here is an example getting raw for (3 byte r,g,b )bytes into an image

```
int width = 256;
int height = 256;
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(height*width*3);

byte[] raw = new byte[width * height * 3];
bb.get(raw);
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(raw, raw.length);
SampleModel sampleModel = new ComponentSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, width, height, 3, width * 3, new int[]{0,1,2});
Raster raster = Raster.createRaster(sampleModel, buffer, null);
image.setData(raster);
```

**Update 2**

For BGR32 I believe this would be closer:

```
ByteBuffer imageData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(height * width * 4);
byte[] raw = new byte[width * height * 4];
imageData.get(raw);
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);
DataBuffer buffer = new DataBufferByte(raw, raw.length);
SampleModel sampleModel = new ComponentSampleModel(
        DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, width, height, 4, width * 4,
        new int[]{2,1,0} // Try {1,2,3}, {3,2,1}, {0,1,2}
);
Raster raster = Raster.createRaster(sampleModel, buffer, null);
image.setData(raster);
```

Notice where I have commented, where I suspect you may need to experiment with the array of bandOffsets in the third argument of the ComponentSampleModel constructor to fix the color model.

**Update 3**

One can reuse the sampleModel to get data out of the image by using BufferedImage.copyData() to a WritableRaster instead of using getRaster().

```
SampleModel sampleModel = new ComponentSampleModel(
        DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, width, height, 4, width * 4,
        new int[]{2, 1, 0} 
);
```

...

```
BufferedImage newImage = ImageIO.read(new File("test.png"));
byte newRaw[] = new byte[height*width*4];
DataBuffer newBuffer = new DataBufferByte(newRaw, newRaw.length);
WritableRaster newRaster = Raster.createWritableRaster(sampleModel, newBuffer, null);
newImage.copyData(newRaster);
```

Comment: this worked! I am still having a problem with color space I believe

Comment: your original answer was correct ( {0,1,2} ). I hadn't tried it thinking I need 4 numbers, so had tried {0,1,2,3} for the image above, and all variants with 4 numbers, but finally read online that BGR32 has only RGB components, and the last 8 bytes are unused... Thanks a lot for your help!